# When do multiple threads access the same code?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

My questions are:

1. Does a Java program, by default, cause creation of only 1 thread?
2. If yes, and if we create a multi threaded program, when do multiple threads access the same code of a Java object?

For example I have a Java program with 2 methods - add() and sub(). In what scenario will 2 or more threads run the 'add()' method?

Isn't code always thread safe, as multiple threads will access different sections of code?

If not, please show an example program where thread safety is a concern.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think of "sections of code", think of where the data lives and how many threads are accessing that actual data.

- Local variables live on the stack of the thread they are being used in and are thread safe since they are different data "containers" per thread.
- Any data that lives on the heap, like instance or static fields, are not inherently thread-safe because if more than one thread accesses that data then they might have contention.

We could get more complicated and talk about where the data *really* is but this basic explanation should give you a good idea of what's going on.

The below code gives an example of an instance that is shared by two threads, in this case both threads are accessing the same array list, which is pointing to the same array data containers in the heap. Run it a couple times and you'll eventually see a failure. If you comment out one of the threads it will work correctly every time, counting down from 99.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable();
        new Thread(r).start();
        new Thread(r).start();
    }
    public static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        // imagine this list living out in the heap and both threads messing with it
        // this is really just a reference, but the actual data is in the heap
        private List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        {  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) list.add(i);  }

        @Override public void run() {
            while (list.size() > 0) System.out.println(list.remove(list.size() - 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Does a Java program, by default, cause creation of only 1 thread?

Really depends on what your code is doing. A simple `System.out.println()` call *might* probably just create one thread. But as soon as you for example raise a Swing GUI window, at least one other thread will be around (the "event dispatcher thread" that reacts to user input and takes care of UI updates).

> 2) If yes, and if we create a multi threaded program, when do multiple threads access the same code of a Java object?

Misconception on your end. Objects do not have *code*. Basically, a thread will run a specific method; either its own `run()` method, or some other method made available to it. And then the thread just executes that method, and any other method call that is triggered from that initial method.

And of course, while running that code, that thread might create other objects, or manipulate the status of already existing objects. When each thread only touches a different set of objects, then no problems arise. But as soon as more than one thread deals with the same object state, proper precaution is required (to avoid indeterministic behavior).

Answer (score 1):

Your question suggests that you might not fully understand what "thread" means.

When we learned to program, they taught us that a computer program is a sequence of instructions, and they taught us that the computer *executes* those instructions one-by-one, starting from some well-defined *entry point* (e.g., the `main()` routine).

OK, but when we talk about multi-threaded programs, it no longer is sufficient to say that "the computer" executes our code.  Now we say that *threads* execute our code. Each thread has its own idea of where it is in your program, and if two or more threads happen to be executing in the same function at the same time, then each of them has its own private copy of the function's arguments and local variables.

So, You asked:

> Does a Java program, by default, cause creation of only 1 thread?

A Java program always starts with one thread executing *your* code, and usually several other threads executing JVM code. You don't normally need to be aware of the JVM threads. The one thread that executes *your* code starts its work at the beginning of your `main()` routine.

Programmers often call that initial thread the "main thread." Probably they call it that because it calls `main()`, but be careful! The name can be misleading: The JVM doesn't treat the "main thread" any differently from any other thread in a multi-threaded Java program.

> if we create a multi threaded program, when do multiple threads access the same code of a Java object?

Threads only do what your program tells them to do. If you write code for two different threads to call the same function, then that's what they will do.  But, let's break that question down a bit...

...First of all, *how* do we create a multi-threaded program?

A program becomes multi-threaded when your code tells it to become multi-threaded.  In one simple case, it looks like this:

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        DoSomeUsefulThing();
        DoSomeOtherThing();
    }
}
MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable();
Thread t = new Thread(r);
t.start();
...
```

Java creates a new thread when some other thread in your program calls `t.start()`.  (NOTE! The `Thread` instance, `t`, is not the *thread*. It is only a *handle* that your program can use to start the thread and inquire about its thread's state and control it.)

When the new thread starts executing program instructions, it will start by calling `r.run()`. As you can see, the body of `r.run()` will cause the new thread to `DoSomeUsefulThing()` and then `DoSomeOtherThing()` before `r.run()` returns.

When `r.run()` returns, the thread is finished (a.k.a., "terminated", a.k.a., "dead").

So,

> when do multiple threads access the same code of a Java object?

When your code makes them do it.  Let's add a line to the example above:

```
...
Thread t = new Thread(r);
t.start();
DoSomeUsefulThing();
...
```

Note that the main thread did *not* stop after starting the new thread.  It goes on to execute whatever came after the `t.start()` call.  In this case, the next thing it does is to call `DoSomeUsefulThing()`.  But that's the same as what the program told the new thread to do! If `DoSomeUsefulThing()` takes any significant time to complete, then both threads will be doing it at the same time... because that's what the program told them to do.

> please show an example program where thread safety is a concern

I just did.

Think about what `DoSomeUsefulThing()` might be doing. If it's doing something useful, then it almost certainly is doing something to some *data* somewhere. But, I didn't tell it *what* data to operate on, so chances are, both threads are doing something to the same data at the same time.

That has a lot of potential to not turn out well.

One way to fix that is to tell the function what data to work on.

```
class MyDataClass { ... }
Class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private MyDataClass data;

    public MyRunnable(MyDataClass data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void run() {
        DoSomeUsefulThingWITH(data);
        DoSomeOtherThingWITH(data);
    }
}
MyDataClass dat_a = new MyDataClass(...);
MyDataClass dat_b = new MyDataClass(...);
MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable(dat_a);
Thread t = new Thread(r);
t.start();
DoSomeUsefulThingWITH(dat_b);
```

There! Now the two threads are doing the same thing, but they are doing it to different data.

But what if you *want* them to operate on the same data?

That's a topic for a different question.  Google for "mutual exclusion" to get started.

Answer (score 0):

1. Depends on the implementation. Only one thread (the "main thread") will invoke the `public static void main(String[])` method, but that doesn't mean other threads weren't started for other tasks.
2. A thread will access the "same code" if you program it to do so. I'm not sure what your idea of "section of code" is or where the idea that two threads will never access the same "section" at the same time comes from, but it's quite trivial to create thread-unsafe code.

   ```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;

   public class Main {

       public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
           List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

           Runnable action = () -> {
               while (true) {
                   list.add(new Object());
               }
           };

           Thread thread1 = new Thread(action, "tread-1");
           thread1.setDaemon(true); // don't keep JVM alive

           Thread thread2 = new Thread(action, "thread-2");
           thread2.setDaemon(true); // don't keep JVM alive

           thread1.start();
           thread2.start();

           Thread.sleep(1_000L);
       }

   }
   ```

   An `ArrayList` is not thread-safe. The above code has two threads constantly trying to add a new `Object` to the same `ArrayList` for approximately one second. It's not *guaranteed*, but if you run that code you might see an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` or something similar. Regardless of any exceptions being thrown, the state of the `ArrayList` is in danger of being corrupted. This is because state is updated by multiple threads with no synchronization.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just one more question. 
As a thread acquires the monitor of an object having synchronized and 'normal' methods, why is it that it will block only the access to the synchronized methods by other threads. How is it that accessing to 'nomal' methods by other threads still allowed?

Comment: @Spires Please dont do that. Dont come back with more question once your initial question was answered. Consider accepting the answer, or to ask for clarification. But not "another thing" comment ping pong. Then: please understand that this community is not a replacement for you studying the basics of java.